# appendChild within Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, onload, appendchild

ok this is a bit complecated to explain so I hope I get this understandable.

I have a table that incluse some linegraphs. The table is working perfectly but the lines are not drawn in IE6 and 7 (8 and 9 are working fine)

I call a function that calculates the lines and then creates a div with that line. Then the function uses appendchild() to include the line in the table.

XHTML

```
<table>
<tr class="outTR">
        <th><h:outputText value="#  {valuegraph}" /></th>
        <c:forEach items="#{valuegraphlist}" var="el">
            <td><h:outputText value="#{value}" /></td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

This is how I call the first function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initgraphics();
});

function initgraphics() {
    var p = $("#imgId_" + firstStep);
    var position = p.position();
    var img = $("img:first", ".stats");
    var i = 0;
    var width2 = img.width() / 2;
    var Y0 = position.top + p.height();
    $("img.img_base", ".stats").each(function() {
        jsBaseX[i++] = $(this).position().left + width2;
    });


    drawLineGraphic(jsBaseX, valuegraph, Y0, "0000FF", "00FF00", true);
}

function drawLineGraphic(BaseX, arrY, Y0, colourDot, colourLine, minus) {

    $.each(BaseX, function() {
        nextX = this;
        nextY = Y0 - arrY[idx];

        doter(nextX, nextY, 4, colourDot);

        lastX = nextX;
        lastY = nextY;
        idx++;
    });
}


function doter(x, y, d,color){
var str="background: #"+color+";
var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.setAttribute("style", str);
ele.setAttribute("class", "class1");
ele.setAttribute("id", "p_"+x+"_"+y);   
document.body.appendChild(ele);
```

}

When the functions get to the appendChild... it crashes...

Any ideas??

Comment: var str="background: #"+color+";

These an unclosed quote here. Is that just in the code above or is that a copy paste from your code as that could be an issue

Comment: Just the code above... var str="background: #"+color+"; I shortened the whole style str thing